# What is the definition of a "data tag"?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been reading about using command blocks, and I come across the term "data tag" a lot. Can anyone explain what this is?

For example:

```
/summon <EntityName> [x] [y] [z] [dataTag]
```

Comment: Got a link or quote showing the usage in context?  Are you thinking of an [NBT Tags](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Tutorials/Command_NBT_Tags) perhaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data tag is a piece of text that allows you to assign NBT (Named Binary Tag, see [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/NBT_format)) data to items or entities.

There are a number of different commands that can be used with data tags to assign NBT data. For more information, check out [this](http://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/1lu48r/13w36a_data_tags_summon_and_give/) post on the Minecraft subreddit.